# Can I rez PAD Campaign before my turn starts?

Tags: android-netrunner

[PAD Campaign](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/pad-campaign-core) is an Asset that reads:

> Gain 1 [Credit] when your turn begins.

Am I allowed to rez it (or other similar Assets such as [Adonis Campaign](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/adonis-campaign-core)) before the start of my turn so I can benefit from it immediately and not give the runner a chance to react to it?

My understanding is that I can rez it after any action by either player, and that includes the last action of the runner's turn. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: Yes you can rez your assets right before the runner's turn ends after their fourth click is resolved. One caveat is the runner current event [Interdiction](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11087) which prevents this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the revised timing diagram from the [Netrunner FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf), it shows a chance to rez cards just before the corp's "Start of turn effects trigger". So yes, you can rez these assets just before the start of your turn and take advantage of the benefit immediately.

You can rez the PAD Campaign after the runner's last action, just before they discard cards, or just before you draw a card, and still gain the credit. It seems best to rez on your turn so if they have to discard they do so not knowing that your asset was a PAD Campaign.